# Using NPM package in the browser with Browserify

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, browserify

I'm trying to use Browserify so that I can use an npm package in the browser. The package I'm trying to use is [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcs)

I have a fcs.js file:

```
// Use a Node.js core library
var FCS = require('fcs');

// What our module will return when require'd
module.exports = function(FCS) {
  return FCS;
};
```

And an index.js file:

```
var FCS = require('./fcs.js');

console.log('FCS IS ');
console.log(FCS);
```

I then ran:

```
browserify index.js > bundle.js
```

And created an index.html file:

```
<html>
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
<script>
    var fcs = new FCS();

</script>
</html>
```

But I end up with the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: FCS is not defined
```

Maybe I'm not grasping the concept correctly. How can i use this package in the browser? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't do this: `require('./fcs.js');`

Do this: `require('./fcs');`

When you `require` something, the extension is implicitly `.js`. Also make sure that your module, `FCS`, has an entry point (the default is `index.js`, but you can change that in the `main` entry in the `package.json`).

Also, in your `index.html` document, you're expecting that `FCS` is a global object. I haven't seen the internal code of `FCS`, but it will only be globally available if it's attached to the `window` object.

When you `require` something, it only makes it available to the rest of your code where it's required. If you want to make it **globally** available, you have to attach it to the `window` object, just like anything else.

In other words, the internals of your `FCS` module might look something like:

```
// node_modules -> fcs -> index.js

var FCS = function() {};

window.FCS = FCS; // this makes it globally available

module.exports = FCS; // this lets you require it
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps. No FCS isn't attached to window object. I can do that in index.js but that doesnt seem to be right think to do as polluting global namespace....

Comment: @Mark, that's the way you do it. Either you attach it to `window` to use it globally, or you don't, and you don't have access to it globally. It's one or the other. Not polluting the global namespace is usually a good idea, but if you're expecting to be able to call `new FCS()`, then you're implicitly expecting `FCS` to be a part of the global namespace. If you don't want that, then don't try to call `new FCS()` in a global context. Instead, do it from the code where you `require`'ed the `FCS` module.

Comment: Thanks, @JoshBeam - this was really helpful. Attaching things to the window object is not discussed at all in the documentation. One question though... might it be possible to attach the `require` function to the window object so one could do `FCS = window.require('./fcs');` outside of the context of the `bundle.js`? This seems a more general solution - only one thing attached to `window`, instead for one of each module you might use. I've been wrestling with this problem at home - I'll try it later.

Comment: @Kryten, I guess so, sure, but I haven't seen that before, and my gut gives me a skeptical feeling about it. Usually when using `require`, the assumption is that you're going to use the require'd code inside another node module or whatever (i.e., not inside an inline script tag, because that's where you'll need the object to be attached to the window)

Comment: @Kryten, another thing too is that this idea of attaching things to a global namespace (like `window`) isn't so farfetched. Angular does something similar when you use it with Browserify and require it (not saying that's an argument for or against the approach... just saying that it works.)

Comment: My use case is for a view model (Knockout, specifically). I need that one object on the page. I *could* attach that view model to the window object & then instantiate it and bind it on the page, but if I've got a large application with lots of models, then my app.js file becomes a long list of `require`s, followed by a long list of bindings on the window object. And re: binding stuff on window - yeah, it makes a lot of sense, but after reading **so many** documents telling me  that doing it is bad, bad, bad... it wasn't clear to me :-)

Answer (score 1):

@JoshBeam's answer is correct - in order to expose assets inside the browserify bundle, you need to attach something to the `window` object. But instead of exposing specific assets, I wanted something more general.

Here's what I did:

in my `app.js`

```
require('this')
require('that')
require('./modules/mycode')
...

window.req = require
```

And in my `<script>` tag in my HTML:

```
something = req('./modules/mycode')
```

Notice that, instead of assigning the `require` function directly to `window.require`, I gave it a different name. The reason for this is simple: if you call it `window.require`, you're overwriting the original `require` and you'll find yourself in an infinite loop of recursion (at least until the browser runs out of stack space).

Comment: very handy, well put

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your inline script (in `index.html`) is expecting a global variable called `FCS` to exist (when you do `new FCS()`). This is not the case because in `index.js`, your FCS variable is scoped to that file.

You should write all your scripts in separate files and bundle them all using browserify, avoiding the inline script or make `FCS` global, by attaching it to `window`.

Comment: So what would I do to index.js to get access to FCS()? If i do "window.FCS = FCS;" it works, but you suggest that is incorrect....

Comment: Josh Beam pretty much covered it in his comment.